# error TS2339: Property 'title' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: angular, firebase

Buenas quiero desplegar mi proyecto en un hosting de firebase, pero al momento 
de escribir "ng build --prod" sale este error.
pero compila normal y no muestra error.
cual seria el problema? 
gracias

```
  getUserById(id: any): void {
    this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
     if (params.id !== undefined) {
      const id = params.id;
      const userResult = 
      this.firestore.collection('users').doc(id).snapshotChanges();
    const editSubscribe = userResult.subscribe((user) => {
      console.warn(user.payload.data(), 'user.payload');
      const userEdit = {
        id,
        // error en esta linea
        title: user.payload.data().title
      };
      this.editForm.setValue(userEdit);
      this.user = userEdit;
      editSubscribe.unsubscribe();
    });
  }
    });
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

El tipo de dato que Firestone da en el método `data()` es `{}`. Tienes que decirle a Typescript cual es el tipo que buscás.

Intenta con `title: (user.payload.data() as any).title`.

Si tenés una interfaz que querás usar, probá con: `title: (user.payload.data() as MyTipo).title`